# NSDate About the date and time display

Tags: iphone, ios

This code.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];  
NSArray *langs = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
NSString *langID = [langs objectAtIndex:0];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:langID];
*format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setLocale:locale];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
strTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[format stringFromDate:today]]; 

today is +0000.    
langID is en.    
but,strTime is Japan time.
```

Why?
I want to show date and time according to the language settings.

Comment: Language != time zone. It's not clear what you want to see here, can you expand the question?

Comment: [NSLocale currentLocale] and [NSCalendar currentCalendar].. take a look at the docs mate

Comment: The user can set a different locale than their time zone. What are you after?

Comment: I want to display the date and time that the user lives.

Comment: @onion, Then why not just use `NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale] ;`?

Comment: ”ACB",Thank you.I helped you again.I just noticed it too.I was able to want to do.Thank you everyone.

Comment: Understand and use the code I also like everyone, I want to make a lot of great work.

Comment: @onion, Glad to know that my answer helped. Can you please accept it so that it will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
NSArray *langs = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
NSString *langID = [langs objectAtIndex:0];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:langID];
```

Try this,

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

That should help.